# How to create a batch file to execute Protractor config file after start the webdriver

Tags: batch-file, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to create a batch file to execute my Protractor **config.js** file, after **update & start** the webdriver. And I have faced the below issues.

```
I tried with below batch code to update and start the webdriver,
But after the webdriver update the cmd prompt closed without starting the webdriver.

@echo on
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
protractor config.js
pause
```

Can anyone help me to create a batch file to start the webdriver and execute the protractor config file.

Answer (score 1):

If `webdriver-manager` is a batch or `.cmd` file, use the `CALL` command to execute it and return. Otherwise you launch the new batch file and it never comes back to yours.

```
call webdriver-manager update
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

To running from batch, instead of calling `webdriver-manager start` just run stand alone selenium server from protractor configuration file.

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone=3.4.0
protractor config.js
```

in configuration file

```
seleniumServerJar: 'node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar',
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. By using the above command in .bat file. Only the update happens and it start executing the config file without starting the webdriver. Got the error message as **Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED**.